# OpenSC on Mac OS X Yosemite

Tags: smartcard, osx-yosemite, opensc

I built OpenSC for Mac and installed it on Mavericks and Yosemite. After the installation Opensc.tokend is added in /Library/Security/tokend directory. On Mavericks it works fine, in Chrome, Firefox, Safari and I can use its tools from terminal too. As for the Yosemite it works in Firefox and I can use its tools from terminal, but I couldn't make it work in Chrome and Safari. My smart card is not added in Keychain. Can anyone tell me what the problem is? Is there any solution?

Answer (score 0):

Do file a proper bug report on OpenSC github (including logs, card information etc)